# Label that changes based upon event handler

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet of HTML that is part of a form where there are two input's. Via CSS I have managed to make the label associated with each input to sit inside their corresponding input to act as a placeholder.

Now, with some standard JS (not JQuery I'm afraid), I wanted to capture the event that the user does (i.e. on a mouse click or keyboard press) on the input and dynamically change the look and feel of the label.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAQ/8/)

The conditions that I need to meet are:

When a user clicks on the input for the first time. The label changes colour to a light grey. After click, if the user then enters a character, the label disappears and the character you have just pressed is displayed instead.

When a user clicks on the input for the first time. The label changes colour to a light grey. After click, if the user then clicks or tabs away from the input, the label changes colour back to it's original state of black.

After entering a few characters into the input, if the user decides to delete the whole set of characters by either pressing backspace deleting each character until none are left or highlighting the whole set of characters with a mouse and presses the delete key, the label appears but is in a light grey colour.

Bug 1: It seems that if you click on the label it starts off going red (as it should be) but when you click away it stays red rather than change to black. However, this isn't a bug if click anywhere on the input but not on the label, it works as it should be.

Bug 2: If you click on the input but not on the label, it goes red and then if you click on the input again but on the label it briefly goes black before going red again (it should stay red as we have not gone away from the input)

Any help you can offer with the JS would be great!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, but is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAQ/10/

Comment: Thanks Kemal. very much appreciate your help. That solves bug 1 but bug 2 is still a problem with the flicker.  Basically if you click on the label twice it briefly changes from red to black and then back to red.  Somehow want to eliminate the bit that goes black and it stays red when you click on the label twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so since the first bug is already solved. This is a solution for the 2nd bug. Basically, you just need to add another selector to one of your CSS rule.

Just add `label.label-inside:active` to the CSS rule for `label.label-clicked`
http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAQ/13/

Since everytime you click the focused label and it switches to the `label-inside` class for less than a second, the `:active` pseudo-class is sort of fired during that event. So you can pretty much just apply the same styling as the `label-clicked` class to that pseudo-class and you won't see any flickering again.